# Jquery keyup or keydown event not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, events, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete textbox that cannot fire the key down event.

Here is the code for the auto complete box

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            // define a function to call your Action 
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("partLookUp", "Transaction")',

                // term will be the param used by your action method
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.pt_part + " " + item.pt_desc1, value: item.pt_part };
                    }))
                    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").removeClass('acLoading');
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").removeClass('acLoading');
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 1, // require at least one character from the user
        search: function () { $(this).addClass('acLoading'); },
    });

});
```

Now here is the event javascript it will never fire... not live or bind or anything for that matter... but the crazy thing is the autocomplete box works...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Transaction Event handlers and ajax calls
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").bind("keydown",function (e) {
        $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").addClass("ui-state-default");

    });
    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").bind("keydown",function (e) {
        $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").removeClass("ui-state-default");

    });
});
```

I tried this way also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Transaction Event handlers and ajax calls
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").keydown(function (e) {
        $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").addClass("ui-state-default");

    });
    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").keydown(function (e) {
        $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").removeClass("ui-state-default");

    });
});
```

I changed to this script to be absolutely sure

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Transaction Event handlers and ajax calls
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TransFinishedPartNumber").keydown(function (e) {
        alert(e.which);
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure it's just not firing and that the issue isn't' that both are firing simultaneously? Try removing the second binding and change `addClass` to `toggleClass`

Comment: In such cases **debug** is who your friend: compose trivial page that reproduces (or often - doesn't reproduce) the issue and inspect it. It's easier to deal with tiny layout and tiny js, rather than with huge project

Comment: you are binding `keydown` twice, so it is immediately adding then removing the class.

Comment: it's still not working even when i make it a simple keydown as the edit above. The page is actually very simple it is just a form with some input fields. I can't understand why it would not fire.

Comment: Maybe autocomplete is binding all the events. Try defining close or change functions.

Comment: Also, could you remove the asp.net-mvc3 tag?

Comment: ok i want to zerkms answered the question... lol i had another script block above this one that i didn't complete just yet and IE stopped at that script so jquery never subscribed to the event... Thanks for the help people i really appreciate it.

Comment: eipipus i am using mvc3 framework and also controllers actions and things like that.. didn't know which one could have caused the problem so mvc3 is appropriate since it is the framework that this code is running in.

Answer (score 0):

Keydown event is fired constantly when you hold the key. You may want to try keyup instead.

Example if you did the following and held something down it would go constantly. In fact many times per second:

```
$("body").bind("keydown",function(){
   $("body").append("pizza<br>");
});
```

but keyup only happens once!

```
$("body").bind("keyup",function(){
   $("body").append("pizza<br>");
});
```

Therefore since your code has keydown events twice. It is adding and removing the class many times per second.